# Change the HTML param from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below Input field and I have the JS to validate the number  of special chars entered in the box. I have a custom help text that appear once the focus in on the Input box.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="words" name="inputHint" placeholder="Enter synonyms"
              data-hint="Enter the words seperated by comma(,)" />
```

The JS to  handle validation is

```
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('words').onkeypress = function (e) {
    // 46 is the keypress keyCode for period     
    // http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html
    if (e.keyCode === 44 && this.value.split(',').length === 2) {
        return false;
    }
}
}//]]>
```

I need help from you on how to change the  `data-hint`  to  a different message like "you have pressed two commas" when there is a  `return false;`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#JavaScript_Access

Comment: `.setAttribute('data-hint', yourNewText)` if you need to support IE lower than 11.

Answer (score 0):

keyup event suits better for this scenario, match value with regular expression.

```
window.onload = function () {
      document.getElementById('words').onkeyup = function () {
          //event.keyCode - do your work with keyCode
          if (this.value.match(/,,/ig)) {
               alert("Your message!");
               return false;
           }
        }
  }
```